# Angular-Strap Modal questions - Controller and Callback Functions

Tags: angular-strap

At the moment I am using the bootstrap-ui modal and it give me the possibility to create an own controller for each modal where I can assing some values from the current form and when I close the modal with the "OK" button an callback function is called, where I can get also some values I've selected in the Modal before when I assing them to the callback function.

And its also possible to open the modal with $q and return the modal as promise.

Are these options also possible with the angular-strap modals? I can't find something about this in the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

I found the AngularStrap documentation (if they want to call it that) quite lacking. You've really either gotta check the source, or find an example elsewhere for many common issues.

Yes, the $modal object can accept promises, but I haven't touched that in a while. I'm a little knowledgeable about Bootstrap-UI's modal implementation and found that it was more robust, so I can't say for certain that you'll find what you need in AS'.